# Angular 6 library add dependency

Tags: jquery, dependency-injection, angular6

I have created an Angular 6 library which uses jquery in it, I have installed Jquery while creating a library and I gave reference of jquery in `angular.json` in root project where I created Library.

```
      "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
       ],
       "scripts": [
           "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
       ]
```

When I consume library in main application it's working.

When I make a library as a pack, then created mylibrary.tgz of my library.
Using `npm install <location of library tgz file>` i install in another application where I need to consume my library.

I am able to access the library but jquery is not found because I did not install jquery in the application that I consume library.

Can anybody tell me how to give dependency of jquery on the library itself when the installed library of jquery also installed automatically in my project?

Comment: you must import jquery library that you added as a module in your code . If you have any problem with importing libraries as a module I will send you a code.

Comment: yea pls can you share me the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)